# kineticjs - set position of multiple images on canvas within a loop

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

How can I set positions of multiple images on canvas within a loop? The following seems to work with:

```
for (var i=1; i<10; i++) {
  images[i]=new Image();
  images[i].onload = function() {
    drawImage(this, 1, 1, i*50, 700, "bulb"+i);
    // THE POSITION CANNOT BE SET ; i IS ALWAYS 500
  }
  images[i].src = folder+src[i];
}
```

Comment: Does this code works? If so, can you make  var m = i*50; alert(m); inside your loop to see if everything is ok?

Comment: Ow, saw your rating... surely cannot help you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `i` has closure outside the function, so its value is tied to what it is at the end of your loop.

You can fix it like this:

```
for (var i=1; i<10; i++) {
  images[i]=new Image();
  images[i].onload = (function(x) {
    return function () {
      drawImage(this, 1, 1, x*50, 700, "bulb"+x);
    };
  }(i));
  images[i].src = folder+src[i];
}
```

This makes a new closure for each onload function, assigning it to `x` each loop iteration.

As a note, this is a rather [common JavaScript error](http://www.apaxsoftware.com/2012/05/common-javascript-mistakes-loops-and-callbacks/)

Comment: Is there any chance to thank you for the hint in another way? It solved my problem!!

Comment: Accepting answers that solve your problem (see the check mark beside the question) is the way to do that around these parts :)